# SQL statement to create a field based on another field for joomla article database

Tags: mysql, joomla

I did a batch upload of articles to my joomla site, this went fine except that the alias field was not submitted, now I have a thousand plus articles with unique titles and they need a title alias. Joomla like to create the title alias with hyphens so

my tile is my-title

how can i batch convert my fields in mysql to add this

in pseudo code

if alias field is '' then fill it with titlewith hyphens

thanks if you know how to do the hyphens thing I think i may with some work find out the sql, I am also asking if this sounds about right and what I need to watch out for...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update MyTable
set alias = replace(title, ' ', '-')
where alias = ''
```

Comment: Thats real neat and tidy, will backup my db tonight and try it. Didn't know that replace function existed.

Comment: This worked great big thanks for contributing to a better internet.